# ElasticSearch Searching for same value on list fields with same name

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Searching for same value on fields with same name. I want return below doc only if all the values are of field "list.perInd" is 'IXSO' ..... 
Original Doc looks like this

```
        {
           "pkClmn": 676101388023,
           "dutyCde": "RICE",
           "list": [
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138804,
                 "perInd": "IXSO",
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138803,
                 "perInd": "IXSO",
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138802,
                 "perInd": "IASI",
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138801,
                 "perInd": "IASI",
              }
           ]
        }
```

return doc only if list.perInd has all 4 IXSO ...

Comment: Can you please add more explanation to your question??

Comment: Well i deleted my answer because i think i get it wrong, can you explain what you want to search and what should be returned?

Comment: or do you mean that you want return documents only if list.perInd has all 4 IXSO?

Comment: yes return doc only if list.perInd has all 4 IXSO

Comment: I have posted possible solution to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current solution could have some performance issues but it works and you should test it

```
POST stack/type1/1
{
  "pkClmn": 676101388023,
  "dutyCde": "RICE",
  "list": [
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138804,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138803,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138802,
      "perInd": "IASI"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138801,
      "perInd": "IASI"
    }
  ]
} 


POST stack/type1/2
{
  "pkClmn": 676101388023,
  "dutyCde": "RICE",
  "list": [
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138804,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138803,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138802,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    },
    {
      "pkClmn": 67610138801,
      "perInd": "IXSO"
    }
  ]
} 


POST stack/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "list.perInd": {
            "value": "ixso"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['list.perInd'].value == value",
          "params": {
            value: "ixso"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me explain a bit about why it work . Elasticsearch use inverted indexes to store data. 
[image: Inverted index]

So when you index document text is tokenized (again there is many tokenizers can be word, can be few words. Read about Elasticsearch tokenizer), In standard token is one word. So in inverted index there is term and refference to documents from our example it takes **ixso** and **iasi** and write them in inverted index. So if you have two terms then doc[fieldname].values will have array of that two terms, in my case i am checking for .value property since it will be cast to string and if there is two tokens string will be different than parameter.

There is also [analyzed and not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) mapping. In my example i show with analyzed and it will work only for one term **perInd**. If for instance you will  index "test word" my solution will not work since **doc['list.perInd'].values** will return **["ixso", "test"]**. And if you use multiple words than you must use not_analyzed

As you see i was also using string parameter to let elasticsearch cache my filter for performance boosting.

[Image from](http://siddhumehta.blogspot.dk/2014/06/elasticsearch-tutorial-inverted-index.html)

Comment: Can you please explain this... I am new to elastic search..  How script part works... Here you are checking list.perInd == IXSO , how it checks all the values are same ??

Comment: Yes, I've the same question too. How does the comparison ensure whether all values in the array are same? But magically your code works. I tested :)

Comment: I've used the same idea to write another query which I think would be easy to comprehend, though I don't know its performance issues. `{"filter":{"script":{"script":"for (value in doc['list.perInd'].values) { if (value != param) return false }; return true","params":{"param":"ixso"}}}}`

Comment: @VinuDominic yes its also possible and performance it would quite the same as my solution.

Comment: @user2526641 I have added explanation to my post hope it make sence and it will help you

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat: The `doc['fieldname'].value` does not convert the array into string as you said, rather it simply returns the first element of the set of terms maintained for that field in the lucene index. You can test this by performing a search using the [Script Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) evaluating the same expression.

Comment: @VinuDominic Yes but try to get length :)

Comment: The reason your script did not fail was because it just happened to return _"iasi"_ for the 1st doc you indexed, thus eliminating it from the search result. Try indexing a document having the value _"WIXSO"_ for one of the `perInd` field keeping rest all occurences to _"IXSO"_. The doc will be returned.

Answer (score -1):

you have some things to pay attention in your data model.
First of all your list is a nested object, you need create a mapping like this

```
curl -XPUT "http://192.168.99.100:9200/testt" -d'
{
      "mappings": {
         "stack": {
            "properties": {
               "list": {
                  "type": "nested"

               }
            }
         }
   }
}'
```

Right now let's insert our example data

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/testt/stack" -d'
{
           "pkClmn": 676101388023,
           "dutyCde": "RICE",
           "list": [
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138804,
                 "perInd": "IXSO"
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138803,
                 "perInd": "IXSO"
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138802,
                 "perInd": "IASI"
              },
              {
                 "pkClmn": 67610138801,
                 "perInd": "IASI"
              }
           ]
        }'
```

Right now let's do a search

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/testt/stack/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
       "nested": {
          "path": "list",
          "query": {
              "filtered": {
                 "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "list.perInd": "ixso"
                     }
                 }
              }
          }
       }

    }
}'
```

We will use a nested query with a term filter, filters can be cached in your case it's the best choice.
I hope it help, if have questions, please ask me.

Comment: Thanks for Answering.. Nested object have low performance than denormalized object.. Thats why we have used denormalized object wherever possible. is it possible to achieve same in denormalized object.

Comment: Nested objects are faster than normal objects, the problem is the query that are you doing. Give me an example of your denormalized data please.

Comment: Above is denormalized.. We didnt mark object as Nested type.. It is plain object

Comment: Just to understand how it will return object which has ALL 4 ixso ? As i see current query will filter if any of them have it or i misunderstand smth?

Comment: How does this answer solve the requirement of OP? It does return the doc even when `list.perInd` has not all _"IXSO"_.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat: Sorry to repeat the comment, I didn't read your's when I posted. Btw, I tried the same query on the same doc in my local and it did return the doc. You're right!

Comment: @VinuDominic Yep, that is why i am asking if i dont understand smth in ES or what, because query will return any document where at least on item has IXSO, but question was about where is only all 4

Comment: @WaldemarNeto: How can you say that Nested objects are faster than normal objects? Inner objects are always faster, easy and performant, if you don't need to maintain one-to-one relation. Nested objects helps you in that, but at some cost. Also, nested objects are faster than the equivalent parent/child wrt read/query performance as the nested docs are stored in the same lucene block as each other. Source: [Managing Relations Inside Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch)